# Left align non-tab indention in R

Tags: r, string, indentation

#### Problem

I'm looking for a nice and robust solution to align indention to the second line.

- second line determines indention size
- indention is a 2xspace
- Text may consist 1:n lines

The issue is to compromise a code formatting and expected look of the output.

```r
text <- "first row from 1st col
    no indention
    no indention
    \tindent by \\t\r
    indent 2 spaces"


cat(text)
# first row from 1st col
#     no indention
#     no indention
#         indent by \t
#     indent 2 spaces


cat(gsub("([ ]{2})+", "", text))
# first row from 1st col
# no indention
# no indention
#     indent by \t
# indent 2 spaces
```

Expected output should look like this

```
Error: first row always from 1st col
    no indention
    no indention
        indent by \t
      indent 2 spaces
```

#### Example solution

I got some solution but it doesn't seem to be elegant

```r
align_left <- function(text) {
  lines <- strsplit(text, "\n")[[1]]
  n_lines <- length(lines)
  if (n_lines > 2) {
    init_indent <- attr(
      regexpr("^[ ]+", lines[2]),
      "match.length"
    )
    
    if (init_indent > 0) {
      for (i in seq(2, n_lines)) {
        lines[i] <- gsub(
          pattern = sprintf("^[ ]{%s}", init_indent), 
          replacement = "", 
          x = lines[i]
        )
      }      
    }
  }
  paste(lines, collapse = "\n")
}

cat(align_left(text))
```

#### Example usage

```r
stop(align_left(text))
```

```
Error: first row always from 1st col
no indention
no indention
    indent by \t
  indent 2 spaces
```

Comment: `text` would always be 5 lines long and would follow the same pattern?

Comment: @RonakShah no, text might be `1:n` lines long but second line always determine indention (indention is always a multiplication of 2)

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear to me. What do you mean by "second line always determine indention" ? Where is the indention in the line "no indention" ? Can you give few more examples which may help to clarify what is expected here?